shiny htmlTemplate not linking correctly to css sheet
I want to add a css file reference to my htmlTemplate for a shiny application. My current method, pointing to an external file, is not working. Removing and replacing the class attribute with style and adding color directly does work.
I feel like this is a path issue. I would add a www folder but I'm using the rhino framework. All files sit within the same folder.
App structure:
template.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    {{ headContent() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" /> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="slider_class">
      {{ slider }}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

styles.css
.slider_class {
  color: #FF0000;
}

app.R
library(shiny)
ui <- htmlTemplate("template.html", slider = sliderInput("x", "X", 1, 100, 50))
server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)


You could try addResourcePath.

I don't love the concept of hardcoding my working directory path, but the comment by @Jan does work.
App structure:
template.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    {{ headContent() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" /> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="slider_class">
      {{ slider }}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

styles.css
.slider_class {
  color: #FF0000;
}

app.R
library(shiny)
addResourcePath("css", getwd())
ui <- htmlTemplate("template.html", slider = sliderInput("x", "X", 1, 100, 50))
server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)

